# Return Two Data Sets

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

So I'm passing a ClientID to my DB and using that to look up all their details, then I want to use those details to also get all other users closely matching the details. I have all this written but my problem is I want to return the initial user's details also. For example;

`Select Details = @UserDetails

from UnregisteredUserTable

where UserId = @UserID`

`Select BunchOfUsersWithMatchingData

from RegisteredUserTable

where UserDetails like @UserDetails`

Obviously I've removed unnecessary info. But as you can see this returns all the data of the matching users but not the initial user's details. Could I use a CTE somehow?

**UPDATE**

Apologies, no idea my data access mattered. I'm doing pretty much the following atm but can change it no problem.

```
Dim results = thisObjectContext.MatcherSP(UserID)

For Each obj In results  
    TableData.Rows.Add(obj.IdNumber, obj.name, 
    obj.emailaddress1, obj.telephone1, obj.telephone2, obj.address1_line1, 
    obj.address1_line2)
Next
```

**UPDATE 2**

ok so I'm just using the two selects in my SP and it runs fine in SQL Server. But when I try to add it to my dbml in Visual Studio I get a strange error:

> Unable to extract stored procedure 'dbo.MySP' because its result set contains muultiple anonymous columns.

Any ideas about that?

Comment: You do not need a CTE for this - but do post your data access code so we can see how you are getting the values from the DB into your application.

Comment: What are the table structures?

Comment: Both tables have the same columns (albeit named slightly differently) plus a couple more that our specific to themselves. I'm only interested in the common columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://twogeeks.mindchronicles.com.dnpserver.com/?p=28&cpage=1#comment-37818

Brilliant article, outlined very clearly exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't VB code, but I will keep it as simple as possible.

Use a SqlDataAdapter to fill a data set. Results from both your select statements will populate different tables in the the DataSet.

```
cmd.CommandText = "MatcherSP";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

You can then access the data as follows:

```
tableA = ds.Tables[0];
tableB = ds.Tables[1];
```

Comment: Really? I could have sworn that if an SP has two select statements one after the other then only the second one is passed back... Will try it out anyways.

Comment: Multiple select statements in one SP is very well allowed. See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure.aspx

Comment: ok so I'm just using the two selects in my SP and it runs fine in SQL Server. But when I try to add it to my dbml in Visual Studio I get a strange error: `Unable to extract stored procedure 'dbo.MySP' because its result set contains muultiple anonymous columns.` Any ideas about that?

Comment: Ya see the database model needs to make the properties it's going to be getting back, so how does it do that when it's receiving two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SqlDataReader`'s nextresult() method.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("NameOfSP",c))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using(SqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(d.Read()){
             //Result data from the first select
        }
        d.NextResult();

        while(d.Read()){
             //Result data from the second select
        }
    }    
}
```